# HTML5 get geolocation function

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to write function that returns the geolocation using html5. However my function never returns. How come?

```
function getCurLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  
        return [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
    });
}
```

Comment: add a `return` before `navigator.geolocation.`

Comment: @karthikr I also tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an asynchronous call.  As with all Ajax, you can't return it's value synchronously with the rest of the code.  You can't know when it will complete or even *if* it will complete.  Any work that relies on the response (`position` in this case) of the ajax call ***must*** be done in the ajax callback.

Comment: Is there anyway to wait until it completes to return?

Comment: @drum as far as I can tell you can't, but why would you want to?  That would lock up the browser until the operation completed

Comment: My application initially gets the current user location. However the user can change its location later on. I don't want the location to reset back to the current location every time the page refreshes.

Comment: @drum then store their chosen location in a cookie or something

Comment: That's a good point. Are javascript cookies compatible with php cookies? (Does this question even make sense?)

Comment: @drum yes (they are) and no (it doesn't, really) since cookies are an HTTP construct rather than a php or JavaScript one